# Переделать калькулятор в калькулятор с потомками c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Нужно чтобы потоки работали во по схеме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это троичный калькулятор,буду признателен за помощь

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TernaryCalculator.Framework;

namespace TernaryCalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        textBox1.MaxLength = textBox2.MaxLength = BalancedTryte.TryteSize;
        textBox1.Tag = textBox4;
        textBox2.Tag = textBox5;
        textBox3.Tag = textBox6;

        textBox4.Tag = textBox1;
        textBox5.Tag = textBox2;
        textBox6.Tag = textBox3;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(mythread1);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(mythread2);

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();
        */

        var x = BalancedTryte.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        var y = BalancedTryte.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        BalancedTryte z = 0;

        switch (comboBox1.Text[0])
        {
            case '+':
                z = x + y;
                break;
            case '-':
                z = x - y;
                break;
            case 'x':
                z = x * y;
                break;
            case '/':
                z = x / y;
                break;
        }

        textBox3.Text = z.ToString();
    }

    private void TernaryTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var target = textBox.Tag as TextBox;
        if (target == null)
            return;

        target.Tag = null;
        BalancedTryte tryte;
        if (BalancedTryte.TryParse(textBox.Text, out tryte))
        {
            target.Text = tryte.ToInt32().ToString();
            target.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            target.Text = "?";
            target.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            textBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        target.Tag = textBox;
    }

    private void DecimalTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var target = textBox.Tag as TextBox;
        if (target == null)
            return;

        target.Tag = null;

        try
        {
            target.Text = BalancedTryte.FromInt32(int.Parse(textBox.Text)).ToString();
            target.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            target.Text = new string('?', BalancedTryte.TryteSize);
            target.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            textBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        target.Tag = textBox;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: А причём тут потоки к вашему калькулятору?

Answer (score 0):

На Вашей картинке описана типичная многопоточная модель "Производитель- Потребитель". Для реализации такого рода многопоточных приложений в С# есть специальные коллекции, к примеру: `ConcurrentQueue`, `ConcurrentStack`. Данные коллекции предоставляют потокобезопасные методы для работы с ними, к примеру для `ConcurrentQueue`: `Enqueue()`, `TryDequeue()`.

Лучшей практикой считается использование данных коллекций совместно с библиотекой TPL и классом `Task`.